# Absolute positioning with varying heights

Tags: css, css-position

I have a sidebar which is fixed to the left edge of the window and has some scrolling content aligned at the bottom of the window. Normally, I could set the scrolling content's container `top` property to the height of the content above it and everything would look ok.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about. And a [more concrete example](http://stevesanderson.github.io/fixed-height-layouts-demo/two-columns.html)

```css
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* and inside sidebar */
#header {
    /* my question is, how do I achieve this effect when this height is 'auto' */
    height: 100px;
}

#scrollable-content {
    top: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

When the content above the scrolling content does not have a fixed height, can I achieve the same effect? Do I need to introduce JavaScript? How might I fix [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94E4Z/1/) so that I can always see the bottom of the scrolling content?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need #scrollable-content and #header to be position:absolute?

Comment: I need this sidebar to be fixed to the edge of the screen and never taller than the window while the main content may scroll. I'm going for something like Gmail's chat - the contacts list scrolls in the left sidebar while the content above it (labels) may change in height

Comment: If browser support is not an issue, then perhaps look at flexbox. If it is, then i think javascript is the only way to go

Comment: I do need to worry about browser support unfortunately. flexbox looks interesting I'll have to check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a few lines of javascript (using jQuery) to find the height of the scrollable area:

```
// find the scrollable height
var scroll_height = $(window).height() - $('#header').height();

// set the height of the scrollable div
$('#scrollable-container').css('height', scroll_height + 'px');
```

Then do the same within the click function after the hide/show so that the new header height is used

http://jsfiddle.net/94E4Z/2/